# Reliable Salesforce JDBC to be used with DataGrip

Tags: soql, sql, database, oracle

Do you recommend any particular JDBC for Salesforce (can be paid) which is reliable enough to be used for commercial purposes along with DataGrip (or similar) software?

I've been checking similar questions like [How can I add Salesforce as a data source in Datagrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897347/how-can-i-add-salesforce-as-a-data-source-in-datagrip) but all the free JDBCs I've came across were quite limited in their functionality. For instance, I was checking this one from http://reliersoft.com and for simple queries against standard objects I was constantly getting `UnsupportedOperationException`.

For development piece, I'm using IntelliJ and Illuminated Cloud but when it comes to database part I'm still looking for a tool that allows me to connect to multiple databases, including Salesforce one. Mostly because we pull out data from Salesforce to variety of databases like Oracle and it would be great to be able to easily switch between them and have some basic support for SOQL syntax as well.